# Query to get all the column names and their type in Squirrel

Tags: squirrel-sql

I am using Squirrel SQL Client to access derby, sql server servers. I can access all the tables and their data from there. Could you please tell me a query to list all the column names, types with no data in Squirrel?

Answer (score 2):

Not that familiar with Squirrel, but generally in SQL you can try:

```
SELECT COLUMN_NAME, DATA_TYPE
    FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.Columns
    WHERE TABLE_NAME='<YourTableName>'
```